# How to handle form submission data ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Still pretty new to ASP.NET. When a user fills and submits a form, I need to write the input fields info to the database. So, first question. Is it best to do this in a button click event, or on page load isPostBack event (if possible, like I said still new). 
Then, I was told to not use raw controls to insert data, ex. INSERT INTO table(Example) VALUES(txtExample.Text).  I can see storing it in a variable first, then using the variable, but is there an even better way I am not thinking of? Maybe something using Request.form["  "]?

Comment: You're really going to want to start with some introductory tutorials on ASP.NET.  Submitting a form with a button and getting the values from the controls is very introductory functionality.  And just about any tutorial is going to cover writing that data to a database.  As a piece of advice... The second half of your question is undoubtedly referring to using query parameters instead of directly concatenating input values into SQL commands.  It has nothing to do with using a variable.  Look up parameterized queries in .NET.

Comment: Perhaps you should start here: http://www.asp.net/web-forms

Comment: Take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/mason-mcglothlin/FancyStoreDemo/blob/master/src/FancyStoreDemo.PublicWebSite/AddProduct.aspx.cs) I created. You can see how it creates an instance of a `Product`, populating the fields from the form controls, then passes it off to a data repository to save to the database. And notice it's all done in the button click handler, rather than `Page_Load`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it best to do this in a button click event, or on page load isPostBack event

Do NOT do it in `Page_Load` - the saving should be the response to some sort of control event (like a button click).

> Then, I was told to not use raw controls to insert data, ex. INSERT INTO table(Example) VALUES(txtExample.Text). I can see storing it in a variable first, then using the variable. Is there an even better way I am not thinking of?

Yes, create a *separate class* that's responsible for loading and saving objects.  The typical method is to create an object in the codebehind, setting its property values to the values from the form (e.g. `txtExample.Text`) then passing that object to another class that saves it to the database, mapping the object properties to database columns however is appropriate.

This is where ORMs like Entity Framework take a lot of the mapping work away - all you do is create an object, add it to a context, set its state to "modified" and EF takes care of all of the column mappings.